# Android App not compatible with some Samsung Devices

Tags: android

I need some help why my app is not compatible with some Samsung Devices like S III, Galaxy Note I and II and Galaxy Tab 2 10.1

Screen:

small
normal
large
xlarge

In my manifiest I have this

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.coffeeandcookies.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: This is a pic of the dev console http://twitpic.com/d05ak8/full. If you need more information, please ask me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Permissions that Imply Feature Requirements](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions) page, `android.permission.CALL_PHONE` implies `android.hardware.telephony`, which of course the Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 does not have. Make sure that telephony is not considered required by adding the following line to your Manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
   android:required="false" />
```

That should get you compatible with tablet devices.

Comment: In my manifiest I have this:

  <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.network"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />

Comment: The strange thing is that SamsungGalaxy Tab II 7.0 and SamsungGalaxy Tab are in the admitted list